# Detect if Variable Contains Number Sequence

Tags: php

I have a variable like this:

33,100,200

I need to detect if it contains a specific number, say

```
if(var contains '33'){
  do stuff
}
```

But it has to not work if say they didn't have 333 in the variable the above statement shouldn't validate the if statement.

Edit: This is a string not an array.

Comment: How is this variable stored? As an array? A string?

Comment: It's stored as a string not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `explode` & `in_array` route, or `preg_match('/(?<![0-9])33(?![0-9])/',$string)` route, I prefer the first.

Comment: The Preg Match Worked the best.

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite understand the second part of your question, but this may be the code you're looking for:

```
if(strpos($var, '33') !== false) {
    // do stuff
}
```

**Edit** Oh, now I think i get what you're looking for

```
if(in_array('33', explode(',', $var)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It's not an array, will that make a difference?